# Is it possible to use my ipod with my PC's internet without wifi?

Tags: internet, ipod

Currently I only have a modem but no wifi, if I plug my ipod to my PC via the usb port, it still doesn't allow me to use the PC's internet. Is this possible to do?

I just want to use my ipod to video call skype, but I don't have wifi nor PC camera.

Comment: USB cameras are dirt cheap these days.

Comment: Yes but I need to do this right now, I see your point though.

Comment: I think it may be technically possible to do it, but it would require jailbreaking and there's no guarantee that it will be supported in the future or that it's risk free. So, it's best to assume that there's no easy way to do what you want. Another possibility besides what ultrasawblade said is getting a Wifi dongle for your PC, making an ad-hoc network and sharing the internet connection with the ipod.

Comment: Does your PC have a built in WiFi CARD at least? Most if not all PCs you buy in your local electronic store nowadays have one built in.

Comment: I don't think it has wifi card. If I get wifi dongle or card, are they supposed to be replacements for wifi routers? Let me check my motherboard model if it has it.

Comment: @JoanVenge You \*can\* use a PC as a router, but in this case, you would be creating a [wireless ad-hoc network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad-hoc_network) between the PC and iPod.

Comment: @iglvzx not necessarily. Windows 7 has a full-blown wireless access-point (infrastructure) host. It can be used side-by-side with the wireless client (on the same card no less). There's a tutorial for it: http://wlanbook.com/how-to-turn-windows-7-laptop-into-wireless-access-point-router/ which actually has an automatic configurator. http://kiekeboe100.hoefman.be/blog/2011/03/creating-an-access-point-in-windows-7/ Goes more in depth for the actual configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can't access the internet connection on your PC through an USB cable connected to your iPod.

Comment: Well hell yeah you can, you just need to set up your pc as an access point and then bridge the connection... IF you have Wifi in your PC...

Comment: If it has a wifi adapter that would work, but the OP clearly said he doesn't have Wifi, only a modem.

Comment: @devius I've heard users say the same, but they still had a Wifi CARD inside their PC even then

Comment: The question clearly states "how to do it without wifi"

Comment: Well if you want to take it that way, he said "without using any Wifi machinery because I don't want the transmission to fry my brain". He could also mean "without connecting my iPod to any wifi network" or "without Wifi, because I don't have a Wifi router". I think it's the last one. But if he doesn't have a Wifi card either, it's useless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get it through your computer without some fancy trickery if possible. Best way is to go to a electronics retailer and buy a modem adapter that will actual turn the internet modem into a wifi hotspot. Be sure to ask the salesperson if you have the right adapter for your modem. Plug it in correctly and both your devices will work.